# Recent statistics on HTML usage in the wild?

Tags: html, research

I have seen some fascinating statistics about what HTML markup is actually in use on the web.

There is [Web Authoring Statistics](http://code.google.com/webstats/index.html) from Google in 2005, and [MAMA](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/mama/) from Opera in 2008.

Have there been any similar studies more recently than this?

Comment: Voting to move to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You probably already know, but the new HTML5 elements such as `<header>`, `<footer>` and `<nav>` were chosen based on the most popular class names found in that Google study. I'm not aware of anything more recent than Opera's 2008 study though.

Comment: It seems important that studies like this are carried out regularly to spot trends. Now that we have new HTML elements such as <header> we need to repeat the study.

Answer (score 2):

This dates from January 2011, but isn't that widespread: http://try.powermapper.com/demo/statsversions.aspx

Comment: This does give fairly recent stats and show the trend over time, but it is only for sites that are submitted to the service, so it may be a very small, biased sample of the web.

Comment: Yes, that seems rather unlike typical numbers to me.

Answer (score 2):

I recently needed to come up with some HTML element statistics.  I downloaded a [600k page web corpus from 2009](http://www.dotnetdotcom.org/#inde) and got the statistics below for number of uses of the tags in that corpus capped at 1000.

```
a                                       39923975
td                                      29707781
br                                      17266040
div                                     15644761
tr                                      15340012
img                                     13539744
option                                  9319944
li                                      8531300
span                                    7573226
table                                   5999791
font                                    5329688
b                                       4419975
p                                       3762731
input                                   3413040
script                                  3368258
strong                                  1855448
meta                                    1809099
link                                    1262896
ul                                      1246231
hr                                      712094
form                                    703914
dd                                      521143
i                                       503215
center                                  483503
h2                                      477122
title                                   446862
body                                    445094
head                                    436058
html                                    435397
h3                                      400073
th                                      393534
em                                      363613
dt                                      363085
label                                   342376
h1                                      318542
select                                  311449
style                                   292716
tbody                                   275069
nobr                                    251825
small                                   242097
noscript                                227474
u                                       227338
area                                    221226
param                                   204798
h4                                      162877
dl                                      142403
iframe                                  126827
o                                       86064
sup                                     72331
h5                                      64141
fieldset                                55447
textarea                                54044
object                                  53226
embed                                   51864
cite                                    47406
scr                                     47050
tt                                      45748
big                                     44210
optgroup                                43329
blockquote                              42869
base                                    42147
map                                     41401
col                                     40191
wbr                                     36995
legend                                  32738
d                                       29939
ol                                      28879
thead                                   27083
spacer                                  26848
pre                                     26118
h6                                      24766
s                                       24510
button                                  23417
code                                    21190
rdf                                     20960
abbr                                    20356
acronym                                 20186
w                                       16818
noindex                                 14038
dfn                                     12974
marquee                                 11350
v                                       11165
strike                                  10522
address                                 9725
description                             9058
sc                                      8677
caption                                 8633
st1                                     8374
colgroup                                8191
item                                    8090
pubdate                                 7160
layer                                   6156
sub                                     5634
ins                                     5433
category                                5106
guid                                    4936
document                                4678
del                                     4639
frame                                   4548
dc                                      4323
image                                   4306
var                                     3729
variable                                3292
tfoot                                   3282
x                                       3120
xs                                      2963
zeroboard                               2870
js                                      2825
ilayer                                  2823
frameset                                2738
media                                   2669
rx                                      2658
author                                  2581
c                                       2563
h                                       2227
ifr                                     2213
xml                                     2134
m                                       2007
csobj                                   1972
n                                       1948
set                                     1872
l                                       1870
permits                                 1848
samp                                    1767
menuitem                                1738
requires                                1732
noframes                                1714
z                                       1686
this                                    1655
q                                       1638
t                                       1629
f                                       1622
content                                 1612
license                                 1533
left                                    1501
srch                                    1488
kbd                                     1482
sfels                                   1466
hs                                      1438
para                                    1434
comments                                1394
changeimages                            1393
list                                    1362
actinic                                 1358
csaction                                1352
skype                                   1338
myarr                                   1337
index                                   1283
blip                                    1279
scri                                    1262
mlp                                     1205
e                                       1199
url                                     1199
basefont                                1167
channel                                 1153
if                                      1152
u1                                      1151
g                                       1137
xsl                                     1137
literal                                 1108
rss                                     1105
itemtemplate                            1053
j                                       1036
blink                                   1022
len                                     1018
id                                      1001
align                                   1000
```

Here are selected tags from HTML5 and others that are less frequent.

```
bdo                                     425
quote                                   123
time                                    61
mark                                    23
bdi                                     5
```

---

## Methodology

I didn't try anything particularly fancy.  I just took the whole corpus (2.4GB gzipped) and ran it through perl

```
gzip -c web200904.gz | perl extractTags.pl
```

where the perl script does

```
use strict;

my %tags = ();
my $count = 0;

sub emit() {
  foreach my $key (keys(%tags)) {
    print "$key:$tags{$key}\n";
  }
  %tags = ();
  $count = 0;
}

sub count($) {
  my $tagname = $_[0];
  $tagname = "\L$tagname";
  $tags{$tagname} += 1;
  if (++$count >= 1000000) {
    emit();
  }
  return "";
}

while (<STDIN>) {
  s/<([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/count($1)/ge
}

emit();
```

I then aggregated the output using a python script.

```
import re

f = open('/tmp/tagCounts', 'r')

counts = {}

pattern = re.compile(r'^([^:]+):([0-9]+)\n?$')

while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line: break
    match = pattern.match(line)
    if match:
        name, count = match.groups()
        count = int(count)
        counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + count

counts = counts.items()
counts.sort(lambda a, b: cmp(b[1], a[1]) or cmp(a[0], b[0]))

for (name, count) in counts:
    print "%s%s%d" % (name, ' ' * (max(1, (40 - len(name)))), count)
```

---

## Caveats

This script uses a very simple heuristic to look for tags, but will be confused by a '<' followed by a word in some contexts:

1. Comparisons in JS or CSS: `<script>if (x<notatag) ...`
2. Commented out tags: `<!-- <notatag> -->`,
3. Non-tag content in `<title>`, `<textarea>`, `<noscript>`, or similar elements.